# Alert box doesn't show static string when its changed from another class but works when i change it from original class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, alert

I have a c# web application. I am trying to show the error to the user which I retrieve from my Data.cs class.
I have a public static string in the code-behind file (Udalost.aspx.cs), and I am adding an error to this string as they appear.

The problem is when I change the text from my Udalost.aspx.cs class everything works okay, but when I change it from my Data.cs(static class) the alert box doesn't show. I have tried stopping on the line where the alert box is called and even change the string value to the same that Udalost.aspx.cs set it(which works fine) and even after that the alert box doesn't pop up, so it probably isn't problem of string value.

Maybe it could be timing, I am calling the method to write alert box at Page_PreRender.
The problem doesn't seem to be string values... new liners (\n;\n), I have tried using the method from Udalost.aspx.cs that is why it is public static but I had no luck.
I tried calling the inner_ShowMessageToUser even directly after the saving to DataBase in data.cs was done and no alert box popped up either.

```
//Udalost.aspx.cs - WebForm2   
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)//after everything is done and before sending to client
        {
            ProvedPredOdeslanimKlientovi();
        }
        private void ProvedPredOdeslanimKlientovi()
        {
            if(ErrorMessage != "")//if some error occured
            {
                inner_ShowMessageToUser(ErrorMessage);//show the allert box called only from one place in app
                ErrorMessage = "";//null the ms
            }
        } 

        public static void ShowError(string error)//add some error to the Error ms and do new line
        {
            ErrorMessage = error + "\\n";//přidej zprávu a odřádkuj
        }
public void inner_ShowMessageToUser(string text)//show the alert box - called only once
    {
        try
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ex", "alert('" + text + "');", true);
            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DeleteCond", $"<script type=text/javascript> alert('{text}')</script>");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            Data.ExeptionHandler(e);
        }

    }


//Data.cs
private static void ShowError(string error)
        {
            WebForm2.ErrorMessage += error+ "\\n";//the same but for Data.cs
        }
```

Comment: Well, when the code in `Data.cs` runs, is it running as part of a request to `Udalost.aspx`? If not, then of course nothing will show up in the browser. But your design here is not good in any case. Have you realised that the `static` string in `Udalost.aspx.cs` is the same for *all* requests? Meaning user A might end up seeing something that was caused by user B:s concurrent request... In web applications you should think hard before using static instance variables/properties...

Comment: Yes thanks for that, BUT my application will be used by only one user at the time and will run localy on a single computer.